# swift - how can I remove blank(empty) line in NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsattributedstring, nsregularexpression

I'm making a Note-Taking-App.
I save **Attributed text** On DetailVC
and I show the preview in the **UITableViewCell label**.

In the label I have a text like this

```
The Bold Title

my Text
```

and I want to change this like

```
The Bold Title
my Text
```

I found the solution in **String**

```
 let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\n+", options: [])
 let newString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: MyString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: MyString.characters.count), withTemplate: "\n")
```

but how can I do it in **NSAttirbutedString**?

pls help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a `NSMutableAttributedString` which is an attributed string which allows mutation of its contents and then use the property `mutableString` of it.

If you already have a `NSAttributedString` you can use `mutableCopy()` or take a look at [possible initializers of NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring).

```
let str = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hardcore\n\nHenry")
str.mutableString.replaceOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "\n", options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length))
print(str)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! but it doesn't have any attributes! how can I fix this?

Comment: You can add attributes as you see fit. For example you can use `str.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSMakeRange(0, 8))` (this is swift3, for swift2.x use `UIColor.redColor()`) to make the word `Hardcore` red. It won't show in `print()` tough. You must use a `UILabel` in order to see what it will look like.

Comment: Thanks... but my problem is replace the attributed text **keeping** it's own attributes. (I used UILabel...)

Comment: How do you convert your string into the `NSMutableAttributedString`? Did you try using `NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: yourStr)`?

Comment: I'm very sorry... that was my fault. It doesn't worked because I add **let** to replaceOccurrence. It works fine now!! Thank for helping!!